# How to create a table with 3 columns in iOS App?(Objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

[image]

Want to create a table as shown in the image in iOS Xcode

Unable to remove space between cells Using Collection view as in the image below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGOSJ.png)

Comment: customize the tableview cell or use collectionview

Comment: use collection view

Comment: collectionview is a good approach to fullfill your requirement.

Comment: I have tried using the collectionview but I have a problem with cell spacing. As in the image I dont want any space between cells. But even if I set minimum spacing to 0 in size inspector there remains some space between cells.

Comment: please set your CollectionViewcell width screenwidth/3. Please recheck its width

Comment: @LalKrishna yes did it that way. Thanks.

Comment: @HimalayaBarad please select my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to achieve this using `UITableView`, you have to customise `UITableViewCell`.

Otherwise its better to do with `UICollectionView`

Answer (score 0):

Using Tableview:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

   UILabel *labelData1 = ...;
   labelData1.text = @"333";
   UILabel *labelData2 = ...;
   labelData2.text = @"56";
   UILabel *labelData3 = ...;
   labelData3.text = @"12";

   UILabel *label1 = ...;
   label1.text = @"Questions";
   UILabel *label2 = ...;
   label2.text = @"Sections";
   UILabel *label3 = ...;
   label3.text = @"Exams";

   return cell;

}
```